# involutes and evolutes

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $$ and $$ be two regular curves defined on an interval (a, b). $$ is an involute of $$ if $(_0)$  lies on the tangent line to $$ at $(_0)$ and the tangents to $$ and $$ at $(_0)$ and $(_0)$  are perpendicular. $$ is an evolute of $$ if $$ is an involute of $$.

Suppose that $\alpha(s)$ is a unit speed curve.

a-if $\beta(s)$ is an involute of $\alpha$ (not necessarily unit speed), prove that

$\beta(s)= \alpha(s)+(c-s)T(s)$, where c is constant and $T = \alpha'$ (I'm not sure about my answer i'll post it below)

b- Under that conditions is $\alpha(s)+(c-s)T(s)$ a regular curve and hence an involute of $\alpha$?  (i'm stuck here)

**Attempted solution for a**

an involute is given in the parametric form as

$\beta(t)= (a(cost+tsint), a(sint-tcost))$

$\beta'(t)= (atcost, atsint)$

$||\beta'(t)||= (\sqrt a^2t^2cos^2+a^2t^2sin^2t) = at$

with this we get,

$s(t)= \int^t_0 a\xi d\xi = \frac{a\xi^2}{2} $ (I don't know how code it but next would be substitute first by 0 then by t)

$ = \frac{at^2}{2}  => t= \frac{\sqrt 2s}{a} $

so the unit speed curve will be,

$\beta(t) = \beta(t(s))= (a(cos\frac{\sqrt 2s}{a} +\frac{\sqrt 2s}{a}sin\frac{\sqrt 2s}{a}), a(sin\frac{\sqrt 2s}{a}-\frac{\sqrt 2s}{a}cos\frac{\sqrt 2s}{a}))  $

this is my attempt at solving a, i'd appreciate it if someone would tell me if i'm correct. and help me with b. thank you all.

Comment: What does this example have to do with proving a and b?

Comment: @TedShifrin I used the parametric form of an involute of a circle of radius a centered at the origin. so it's completely wrong? if you could just tell me what steps I should do and i'll try it on my own. i'd really appreciate it, thanks.